# Is it possible to write native or access native code in F#

Tags: f#

Is it possible to write native o access native code in F#? i know F# use .Net sdk but i want to know is it possible to load Native C++ dll or directly use bytes?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use P/Invoke:

[How to: Call Native Libraries from F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh304361%28VS.100%29.aspx)